# How to add text in newline in Textview while testing using Robotium testing framework?

Tags: java, testing, apk, robotium

I am testing an APK using Robotium testing framework. I want to add some text in textview in such a way that abcd is on first line and efgh on 2nd line. I tried following code but it doesn't seem to be working.

How can I add newline in Textview using Robotium framework.

```
public void test_Test1() {  

        fob308 = "abcd"+ "\n" +"efgh";
        solo.enterText(0, fob308);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `android:singleLine="false"` in layout?

What about `System.getProperty("line.separator")` instead of `\n`?